# Getting error while connection to sqlserver services in ms

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I have different ways to configure SQL Server services but couldn't able to solve this below problem.

I have SQL Server 2012/ 2008 installed in my PC with reporting server.

Below are errors I am getting.

1. Reporting Services Configuration manager.

I have configured SQL Server reporting Service and then trying to open report server URL it's showing error "Service unavailable". I have googling from many days but I couldn't find any solution for this.

[image: Service unavailable Error]

2. I am trying to connect Reporting services from Management studio also getting error.

[image: Unable to connect reporting Service in SS Management studio]

3. Even tried to install SQL Server 2008 and trying to configure SSRS server also getting problem to connect.

[image: Can't configure report serive in 2008 Version]

I hope I am missing something in configuration. Let me know.

Thanks,
San

Comment: What Version of windows are you on - I have never been able to get report services to "work" on home editions....What edition of SQL server have you installed - if express you will need to qualify your server name to include \sqlexpress. and you could try using windows authentication

Answer (score 0):

Please check Reporting Services is up and running on machine.

If not up and running please start service .

if still do not work then try following steps

1. Change SSRS service to run under Local System Account
2. Test the service if SSRS starts.
3. Drop and Recreate SSRS service account from/in Windows Active Directory
4. Remove SPN and Re-ADD the service account for SSRS service account.
5. Remove the account from SQL Server and Re-add back with the required privileges. Not doing so will cause authentication failure.
6. Under SQL Server Configuration Manager, change the service account back to the old one.
7. Test if the solution works. You might have to delete the encryption keys as well.

Comment: Hi i am unable to follow step 3 and 4 ..please let me know how to get SPN and re-add.

Comment: As i mentioned error no 3: any idea why report server instance is empty for MS Sqlserver 2008.